# Filtering maximum and minimum length in QGIS Attribute table

Tags: qgis, expression, filter, formula, numeric

My Dataset contains the field `"length"` with numbers from 1 to 100. I just want to filter data which are greater than 50 or which are less than 50.

I just use the formula:

```
"Length" < 50 And "Length" > 100
```

But this filters data into series.

Comment: I don't understand what your target is. If you create a filter for data whose `length` attribute is greater than 50 or smaller than 50, you will get the whole data set. Also, in your example, you use `"Length" > 100` which will yield no data since you don't have values over 100. I guess you should duplicate your layer and set a filter `"Length" < 50` in one of them, and `"Length" > 49` in the other one

Answer (score 5):

The logical operator should be [`OR`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#or) instead of [`AND`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#and).

```
"Length" < 50 OR "Length" > 100
```

See [Logical connective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_connective#Natural_language) for more details.

Another solution will employ [`NOT BETWEEN`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#not-between) operator:

```
"Length" NOT BETWEEN 50 AND 100
```